# copy multiple files to multiple "folders with Unicode names"

Tags: windows, file-transfer, unicode

i have 29000+ mp3 files which have English names , i want to move or copy subgroups of the files to multiple folders with Arabic names, i have a list of each file and where it needs to go, i could use the `move` command from the cmd prompt if the folders were in English but it doesn't work with Unicode names Or i can rename the folders to non-unicode names then use the `move` command then rename the folders back to their original names But i dont want that ..my question is is there a command line utility or any utility in general or a script that can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve that by changing the code page number in command window, i used the command `chcp 1256` inside a batch file , then i saved the batch files with **arabic 1256** page encoding and it worked.
cheers